# unit testing with symfony + doctrine + PHPUnit

Tags: unit-testing, symfony1, doctrine, phpunit

I'm working with Symfony + Doctrine + PHPUnit, with NetBeans IDE. Here' my current approach to unit testing.

- setUp() function loads the test fixtures from .yml files
- tearDown() function delete all data from models. this is done by looping through an array of all my models' names to something like Doctrine_Query::delete($modelName)->execute()

This seems to work, but i'm just curious if this is the correct way to do it. I am essentially clearing all tables after each test function by specifying the models/tables to 'delete all' from.

Q1: I am just wondering if this is the correct way...
Q2: this works nicely in Netbeans IDE, but does not seem to work via "./symfony test:unit". am i missing something or the CLI just works with lime?

Comment: To post a more updated answer, Symfony 2 uses PHPUnit for testing.
You can [check the manual](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

./symfony test:unit runs symfonys own test suite that is using lime as a test framework, and not phpUnit.

And netbeans uses phpUnit for its integrated test support. hopefully netbeans will add test suport for symfony test suite in their incomming symfony suport in netbeans 6.8

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use phpunit with symfony check out: [PHPUnit plugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfPhpunitPlugin) Just a note that this only works with 1.2.x it seems, for 1.4.x which is what I'm currently using at work check out: [Another PHPUnit plugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfPHPUnit2Plugin) this last one is in beta, but it works for 1.4.x according to the author, I'll be trying it out soon, so if I can remember, I'll come back here and throw up my findings. It's honestly not to hard to back out if you don't want to install it, so trying it is easy.

If you happen to try it, please post your findings, I'd be really interested in hearing your thoughts. I'm finding lime to be lame (HAH!) as it just makes mocking a chore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying it externally with PHPUnit, no plugin. I'm using Doctrine. I am having quite a problem. If I run ONE PHPUnit (written by me) tes method, it's great. The second one, not so good. It may be the way I'm using Doctrine. It seems like even though I delete everything from the database (between PHPUnit Method calls) and restore the fixtures file, all in the setup(), DOCTRINE remebers previous values.

Doesn'jt matther whether I flush the connection, unset the parent object that is being erroneiously 'remembered', refreshRelated() etc, I still get old values when I do the first assignment to a relationship.

$parent=new ParentType;
//set parent values.
$child=new ChildType
//set child values
$child['Parent']=$parent;
$child->save();

The database is reflecting everything fine, it's Doctrine in PHPUnit that's not working. I haven't tried it OUT of PHPUnit yet, after all, test before use, right? But I  may have to do that and see if it's Doctrine or PHPUnit